# prove it has basis property

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine the dimension of the following $K$-vector space $V$, by specifying each having a basis and proving they have Basis property.

1. $K=\mathbb{R}, V= \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1-2x_2+3x_3=0 \}$
2. $K=\mathbb{R}, V = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) \;\Bigg|\; a+d=0 \right\}$

For the first one I think that it is a $2$-dimensional vector space. The basis is $(2,1,0), (-3,0,1)$, but I dont know how to solve it in a mathematical way.

Comment: We are not here for doing your homework for you. Please specify what you have tried to do and where you are stuck.

Comment: So you have made a guess, now prove it: show that these two vectors satisfy all properties in the definition of a basis. Do you know the definition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. $$
   a \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2a - 3b \\ a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   So can this equal zero when either of them are non-zero (are they linearly dependent?). If we have
   $$
   x_1 - 2 x_2 + 3 x_3 = 0
   $$
   can we find $a,b$ so that
   $$
   a \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   If you can then indeed these vectors span the space, thus combined with the result above makes this a basis.
2. A basis of $M_2$ is
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   However clearly this won't work for our space, which vectors here can you pick out and modify to work for our space?